# Change several texts color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a widget containing many different `Text()` widgets in it.

How could I change all of these widgets color to white at once without modifying one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you can use variables

```
class yourclass extends StatelessWidget {

Color mycolor = Colors.red; // define your color here.

                  Text('some Text',style:TextStyle(color: mycolor),),
                  Text('another text', style: TextStyle(color: mycolor),)
```

Comment: I know I could something like that but still have to modify all of them. I was thinking on something more similar to css, where we have the parent element and we apply a style to it

Comment: that is not possible in flutter

Comment: Ok, just wanted to double check to be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can think about ThemeData - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: but that is gonna change the whole app style right?

Comment: Nope. You have everything described in linked cookbook. Check 'Themes for part of an application' part.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to double check to be sure. Thanks!